# Datatable sorting for date not working on FF

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I'm trying to use datatable.js and moment.js for sorting dates on a table. It's working well on Chrome browser but not working on Firefox.

Here's the code for review.

```
$.fn.dataTable.moment('MM, DD, YY');
$('#dataTable').DataTable( {
    info: false,
    paging: false,
    searching: false,
});
```

Also here's the link for review the result
https://jsfiddle.net/8phz4rn2/24/

Any ideas how this can be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Your direction is correct, in regards that you are trying to parse the date from a given string and display it in a table. The problem here is that DataTable is not aware of any `moment` operations you did before, so it is displaying the row values as original strings. So the column is sorted by strings, rather than dates.

You must convert the strings to dates inside the DataTable `render` function, just before it displays it to the screen.

```js
$('#dataTable').DataTable({
  info: false,
  paging: false,
  searching: false,

  "columnDefs": [{
    "targets": 0,    // column index, 0 means the first column
    "render": function(data) {
      return moment(data, 'MM/DD/YY').format('MM/DD/YY');
    }
  }]
});
```